# A good place to start?

Tags: amateur-observing, cosmology, astrophysics

I am a high school student (going into 11th grade next year), who will be taking an introduction to astronomy and astrophysics as part of my core curriculum. As such, I would like to get a head start now, but I am not sure where to start.  Are there any specific learning resources that are recommended? Books, videos, documentaries?

Comment: While I'm not trying to discourage you from learning, this site is about specific astronomy concepts. So I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: It probably will get closed, but if you know the teacher, or students who've already taken the class, start there.   Astronomy can be approached in a classroom a few different ways and Astrophysics could take it closer to a physics course depending on the teacher.    I love astronomy as a hobby, but I wouldn't know what to recommend cause the curriculum isn't well defined.

Comment: This is not a good question title.

Answer (score 1):

Find a local astronomy club; they will help you get started, learn the sky, and show you different types of equipment. Also, read "Turn Left At Orion", H.A. Rey's "A New Way to See Them" and "Find The Constellations" to learn the sky.

And get a pair of 10x50 binoculars. These are the best "telescope" (actually, two telescopes!) to start with: inexpensive, wide-field of view to find objects (anti-soda straw effect), and 100x the light gathering power of the naked eye.